# How is Localization in Laravel implemented?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to implement localization on my website using **Laravel 5.5.**
However, I am not sure what the standard practice when using localization should be. I have used the LocalizationController module from the Laravel documentation. My goal is to have the localization option selected via a dropdown. Then the user's selection should be remember.

**Do I store their selection in a database for future use?
Or, is this something to keep in a cookie?**

Side note:
(I want to avoid having their selection in the url. I'll either pass the data in a request or get method.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For registered and logged-in users i recommend to store the users language in the database. Everytime a user logs in the application should set the language for the current user. Maybe you take a closer look on [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware). Build a language middleware, register it as new middlewaregroup and assign it to every route (-group) you need. A middleware could look like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LanguageMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            // user is logged in
            App::setLocale(Auth::user()->language);
            return $next($request);
        }
        App::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Now register the new middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php` as new middleware-group under `protected $middlwareGroups`:

```
// other middleware-groups
'language' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\LanguageMiddleware::class
]
```

Finally assign middelware-group to route (-group):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['language']], function(){
    // Routes...
});
```

Unfortunately there is no build-in function to show a dropdown-language-select. But you can simply build a blade-partial which you can integrate in your navbar or where-ever you want to show/use it. You could ask new users during registration for their preferred language.

Guests/unregistered users could use the dropdown. By default they should see the default language.

Hopefully this helps you.